# CLONE_IO does not fit into the range of the "flags" parameter of clone()

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, c99

According to the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) of `clone`, the third parameter of `clone` (`flags`) is of type `int`. The man page offers to pass `CLONE_IO` through this parameter, which, however, [seems](https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/include_2uapi_2linux_2sched_8h.html) to be defined as `0x80000000`, which is of type `unsigned int` in C and, thus, has a value not representable by `int` (because `INT_MAX` is equal to `0x7FFFFFFF`).

Thus, if I use

```
clone (..., ..., CLONE_IO | ...,
```

then gcc outputs: `error: signed conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ changes value from [[some positive number]] to [[some negative number]] [-Werror=sign-conversion]`.

I suppose that the idea of this flag was not to force the user to disable certain warnings globally or to do an explicit cast of the argument before passing. Is this a design error or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type conversions are implicit in C programming language. Your compiler is broken, as it terminates the compilation and issues a diagnostic on such implicit conversion.

This is questionably a design error, but it is *you* who configured your compiler to be non-standard. I think this could be fixed with `(int)0x80000000`. I think you could fill a glibc bug report, but I think there will be reservations with changing such ancient code.

> 0x80000000, which is of type unsigned int

Or `int` or `long` or `unsigned long` depending on the size of the types.

Comment: In the C99 standard, in "6.3 Conversions" -> "6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers", it is written: "_When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool (...) Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised._" As I understand that, the standard says that, e.g., after `int a = 0x80000000`, the value of `a` may be different across different implementations, even if they all have `int` width 32.

Comment: Yes, it may be different. But the compilation _has to_ proceed. Also the implementation-defined behavior is documented https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation .

Comment: Thank you, so "_For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N to be within range of the type; no signal is raised._". But does the man page of `clone()` tell me that this is what is needed? I could also use another compiler which converts `CLONE_IO` to something else, which `clone()` does not expect.

Comment: Glibc is a library, written for a specific purpose for a GNU system with a specific kind of ABI. `he man page of clone() tell me that this is what is needed?` Man page is documentation, not specification. `I could also use another compiler` I do not understand. Yes, you could, and the result will depend on the exact ABI difference and implementation of clone(). If clone() was compiled for that ABI, and does a proper syscall, all will be fine.

Comment: Anyway, the point is, the expectancy is that glibc is written for standard compatible compiler with GNU extensions. My answer is, that you can't expect glibc code to compile with a non-standard compiler. If you are using such compiler, that limits C programming language by prohibiting some internal feature, it's on you that standard compatible code doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you, so the point is that not only the compiler is the "implementation" (in terms of C terminology), but the combination of the compiler and the library that it uses for `clone`. And as long as both of them are compatible, it does not matter what signed number `CLONE_IO` is converted to.